# How is this situation possible with SpringSecurity and Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security

Given a controller method annotated with 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULL', and the injected springSecurityService, I am puzzled why occasionally I am seeing exceptions being raised due to a null user instance.

E.g.  My controller action is as such..

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
  def ammendSomething = {

    def User user = springSecurityService.currentUser

    println user.fieldTest
    render "OK"
  }
```

Heavily altered to show the important bits,  the annotation, the call to retrieve the user and accessing the field.

The above results in a NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'fieldTest' on null object

This is only happening in production and I haven't been able to replicate the issue in development as any calls I make to this when not logged in, I am correctly redirected to the 'auth' login process.

So I'm pretty baffled how the situation arises that the pringln user.fieldTest is getting executed when there is no currentUser in springSecurityService.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What is `def User user`? I'm surprised that even compiles. Remove the `def`.

Comment: It's groovy code, just with an explicit type declaration